# Defining a piecewise function from a sequence of functions

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

I'm attempting to define a piecewise function from a sequence of defined functions.  I've attempted something like this:

```
Do[f[i_][x_] := x^i, {i, 1, 5}]
Piecewise[{{f[1][t], 0 < t < 1} Do[{, f[i][t], i - 1 < t < i}, {i, 2, 5}]}]
```

However, this approach fails.  Does anyone know how to do something like this?  My list of functions could become very large, and creating the piecewise function manually would become very tedious.

Comment: `Piecewise[Table[{f[i][t], i - 1 < t < i}, {i, 5}]]`

Comment: If there is a simple rule (like the ones in your examples) then it might be easier to just define the function directly... for example, `f[i_Integer, x_] := x^i` defines *all* at once.

Answer (score 4):

In this case I will directly go for something like `Floor`

So your program could be easily written as:

```
g=f[Floor[#]][#]&
```

This will be much more direct and will be faster as well when dealing with a huge amount of choices. But if in your real cases, the first element cannot be easily written out in similar ways, then this will not be that applicable.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to get your sequence of functions, `f[i]` defined correctly.

```
Block[{x}, Do[f[i][x_] = x^i, {i, 1, 5}]]
Definition @ f
```

[image: ffunc]

Now you can use what Feyre suggested in a comment to your question.

```
Block[{t}, g[t_] = Piecewise[Table[{f[i][t], i - 1 < t < i}, {i, 5}]]];
Definition @ g
```

[image: gfunc]

Note: I use `Block` to protect the free variable `x` and `t` from evaluating to values they might have received at top level.